# Embed .m3u8 file in html

Tags: video-streaming, embed, m3u8

I've got this file:

```
http://50.7.191.250:8080/hls/main/tvp2.m3u8?token=ee4091dc1db99d678bcc70a1460d724a19f9becf
```

I'm trying to embed it in html page. Has anyone got any idea what tools do I need to watch this video online and how to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i embed this m3u8 into my webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271658/how-do-i-embed-this-m3u8-into-my-webpage)