# How do i embed this m3u8 into my webpage?

Tags: html, streaming

My title says it all. i have m3u8 file i need to embed

tried using this method(below) but it says "video format or mime type is not supported"

```
<div id='player'>
            <video width=100% height=100% src="http://cdncities.com/deranalive/deranalive/playlist.m3u8" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" controls autoplay>
            </video>

</div>
```

i tried [jwplayer wizard](http://www.jwplayer.com/wizard/), on there it works, but it not free.... i am dont know what to do.

anyone know a free player? or solution for that code?

thanks.

Comment: Simply including it in the video tag should work. Maybe the issue is in your M3U8 file itself (one of the videos referenced is not supported on your browser). It would be useful to include this and also the browser console output which may have more info. BTW, I don't think you should need the 'type="application/x-shockwave-flash" - have you tried it without this?

Comment: i tried it still did not work.

Comment: You need to post the browser console output and also the video url if possible, and post the m3u8 file. Not all video formats are supported on all browsers so this is not an unusual error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only Safari 6.0+ has native HLS support. You can't use it with HTML5 on a desktop.

A free player that supports HLS via Flash is [mediaelement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/)

[mediaelement.js - HLS Demo](http://www.flashls.org/mediaelement/demo/mediaelementplayer-hls.html).

Comment: is it possible to host the video without installing it to the website root?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You need to add mediaelement.js to your site but the source stream can be a live-stream like in your example.

Comment: hmm the i tried the example, but it didnt work , then i copied the whole website to see if it works it didnt... but anyways i figured out another way of doing it.  thanks

Answer (score 10):

easy sir you can follow this file:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@latest"></script>
<video id="video"></video>
<script>
  if(Hls.isSupported()) {
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    var hls = new Hls();
    hls.loadSource('http://cdncities.com/deranalive/deranalive/playlist.m3u8');
    hls.attachMedia(video);
    hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED,function() {
      video.play();
  });
 }
 // hls.js is not supported on platforms that do not have Media Source Extensions (MSE) enabled.
 // When the browser has built-in HLS support (check using `canPlayType`), we can provide an HLS manifest (i.e. .m3u8 URL) directly to the video element throught the `src` property.
 // This is using the built-in support of the plain video element, without using hls.js.
  else if (video.canPlayType('application/vnd.apple.mpegurl')) {
    video.src = 'http://cdncities.com/deranalive/deranalive/playlist.m3u8';
    video.addEventListener('canplay',function() {
      video.play();
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Worked great. Just make sure if you run https to use https stream, with http use http stream and check ports for each stream.